# Segmenting AJAX responses in perl CGI?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, cgi

Is it possible for a perl cgi script to segment its AJAX responses into numerous individual HTTP responses?

Say I have this code:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        onDataReceived(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    else if(xmlhttp.status!=200 && xmlhttp.status!=0) {    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","script.cgi",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(toURLString(options));
```

as javascript (dont tell me about xml object compatibility issues with ie, I know, and don't care).

and this:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my %form = Vars();
if($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq "POST" )
{
    $|=1;
    for(my $i, (1..100000000))
    {
        print "1\n";
    }
}
```

as perl cgi. Is it possible to print out this result in numerous individual packets of 1s, instead of generating 100000000 1s before finally having an output?

Comment: re "dont tell me about xml object compatibility issues with ie, I know, and don't care", you probably also want to say something to keep people from telling you about jQuery and friends

Comment: Obligatory: You should drop whatever you're doing and use jQuery instead!!! (and I don't even know jQuery... *sigh*...) now that we got that over with, my actual answer is below :)

Comment: I do use jQuery, for some reason I don't like the jQuery AJAX syntax, so that's the only part of my code that falls back on normal javascript. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this SO question for possible approaches, though it's not Perl specific:

[Dealing with incremental server response in AJAX (in JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155066/dealing-with-incremental-server-response-in-ajax-in-javascript)

From the linked Wiki article, this link seems most relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#XMLHttpRequest

**However, I would strongly suggest considering a polling approach instead of the "server push" one you are considering**:

The server stores the chunks of data as accessible files (with some ordering meta info)

```
print "Location: xxxx"; 
# Sorry, forgot the exact form of Location HTTP response.
# Location points to URL mapped to /home/htdocs/webdocs/tmp/chunk_0.html
my %form = Vars();
if($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq "POST" )
{
    $|=1;
    $file_num = 0;
    my $fh;
    for(my $i, (1..100000000))
    {
        if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
            close $fh if $fh;
            open $fh, ">", "/home/htdocs/webdocs/tmp/chunk_${file_num}.html";
            # Add the usual error handling on open/close i'm too lazy to type
            $file_num++;
        }
        print $fh "1\n";
    }
    print $fh "\n##############END_TRANSMISSION__LAST_FILE####################\n";
    # This was a singularly dumb way of marking EOF but you get the drift
    close $fh;
}
```

The AJAX poller retrieves them in a loop one by one, processing the response containing the next chunk and looking for meta-info to know what (and if) the next piece to poll for is.

Comment: Obviously naming schema needs improvement, e.g. include session ID or timestamp of request, for concurrency reasons. Plus implemt a separate CGI to clean up, which could be called via AJAX once the last response is read in.

Comment: Just to be clear - the above code was meant as a rough illustration of the idea, not a good well-designed or well-implemented actual solution.

Comment: Awesome solution, I tried this out and it works, now I'll have to decide whether the design of solution fits in my program. Thanks :)

Also "# Add the usual error handling on open/close i'm too lazy to type" hahaha, that probably took just as much writing as"or die "unable to open";" hahah

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess it is probably wise to send the client back a response to let the javascript know that an output is started in the file.

Comment: @Razor Storm - FYI - the `die` message should always include `$!` for IO errors; and I generally hate dying in a web app... which is why I did a generic "insert error handling here" hand-waving instead :)