# PHP/JS Ajax - Displaying the PHP page as it loops through array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a page, videos.php, that loads a video feed through Ajax. On the php ajax page, video_feed_ajax.php, it looks through an array creating a  object for each video. However, the current way I have the JS written, it only displays the video_feed_ajax.php when its completley loaded (when its looped through the entire array).
->Is there a way to display the video_feed_ajax.php each time it goes through the loop, so the videos are shown as it loops through instead of just at the end?

The portions of my JS that apply:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChangedUsersAddVideoFeed;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

function stateChangedUsersAddVideoFeed()
{
    document.getElementById("add_video_feed").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById('add_video_feed_load_img').style.display='none'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* call the [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function inside your loop in PHP to immediately send the echoed mark-up.

But if your loop is taking long enough to be a nuisance there **must** be something wrong with it - unless you just want the visual effect of progressive loading, in which case you should simply animate that after receiving the whole response. There is no point in streaming just a few kbs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to display the video_feed_ajax.php each time it goes through the loop, so the videos are shown as it loops through instead of just at the end?

I'm going to interpret this to mean:

> Is there any way to process the data from the query as it comes back from the server, rather than process the entire document at once?

To which the answer is "probably not," in this specific case.

You're writing ajax on the bare metal here, and are blindly assuming that *any* readyState changes are going to be in your favor.  (This is bad practice, by the way.  Have you considered using a modern Javascript library, like jQuery?)

[The issue at hand is what those readyStates are](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handler-attributes),  and when they're triggered.  The states are:

0: Unsent: The object exists.

1: Opened: The object is in the process of making the HTTP request.

2: Headers Received: The request has been made and HTTP headers have been returned.

3: Loading: The HTTP request body is being transferred and processed.

4: Done: The HTTP request body has been loaded completely.

Different browsers handle 0, 1 and 2 differently, so let's pretend that they don't exist.

Now, the spec says that [the response *should* be partially populated as it's made available](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#response-entity-body), but your code only ever fires when the state changes.  You're only ever going to see two state changes: it's Loading, or it's Done.  That means *your existing code will never, ever see the partial document!*

Now, my gut instinct is that you could set up a `setTimeout` when the readyState is Loading and then constantly poll the response to see what changed, but that's unlikely to work.  [As documented in this previous question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155066/dealing-with-incremental-server-response-in-ajax-in-javascript), **some browsers don't implement the Loading readyState!**  That means **your code can only ever reliably see the Done readyState.**

In summary, you can't do this... without some help.

The HTML5 effort proposes a new technology called [Server-Side Events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/).  It's designed to do exactly what you're trying to do here: send isolated chunks of data, one at a time, back to back, and process them independently.  There are native implementations in Chrome and Opera, and [there's a jQuery plugin to emulate the interface](https://github.com/rwldrn/jquery.eventsource) when the browser doesn't implement it.  They wanted to slip it into Firefox 4, but they couldn't quite make the cutoff.  I only know that this technology exists, not that it works will or is suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I went with a combination of both of your answers. I added flush() to the end of my PHP loop, and changed my JS code to the following. It may not be 100% reliable, but its the best solution I have. THanks guys!

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==3)
{
    document.getElementById("add_video_feed").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
    document.getElementById('add_video_feed_load_img').style.display='none';
}
```